# any way to encode to mp3 using php without paying fee

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mp3

Is there any opeensource library available for php that we can use to encode mp3 without paying fee. I will be using mp3 encoding on my website. If not can you tell me how much fee we have to pay for recording ten minutes sound clip.

Comment: There is no library for PHP natively, no. Can you access the command line on your server from PHP? Can you install/use command line programs?

Comment: then run lame: http://lame.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legally, no, mp3 is patent encumbered so you have to pay to use it.  That's not to say that libraries don't exist, just look at the long list of products that exist to rip a CD into mp3 encoded files.  However, if you are putting it on a public website, you really should do this the proper way.

Comment: can you tell me where i can buy mp3 license.

Comment: That's not true. The MP3 software patents are mostly invalid outside of the US. Non-commercial usage cannot incur a fee anyway.

Comment: I'd also suggest looking into OGG for a free alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **ffmpeg** library for encoding, from [here](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/). You need to install an extension (probably "**ffmpeg**") in your Apache, whether it be in your local machine or in the server. For the latter, you can ask the server administrator to do the installation, but provide specific information as to which version of the extension you want to get it installed.

**Note:** There are differences with this extension version & the PHP version.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at mencoder and ffmpeg . both can encode mp3, you can execute them
on command line from your php script.
But as @BMitch said, try to be sure about patent and fees issues.